# string of /static/media/~ was displayed instead of its markdown content in react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, markdown

while I referred to material ui [blog](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/templates/) template,I develop my blog [app](https://github.com/hikaru0706/MyBlog/blob/main/src/Blog.tsx#L15-L17),I import markdown file as `import post1 from './blog-posts/blog-post.1.md';`

after that,these properties are passed to [this](https://github.com/hikaru0706/MyBlog/blob/main/src/Main.tsx#L31) component,as `<Markdown className="markdown" key={post.substring(0, 40)}>` I intended to show its content in 40 letters.

But it returned following path. it seems that build path of this content

```
0: "/static/media/blog-post.1.50d9283f83f7cfcc4000.md"
1: "/static/media/blog-post.2.8e855c6626746019d87c.md"
2: "/static/media/blog-post.3.f65a9b04dd86fcb4de03.md"
```

My desired result is like following,content shold be displayed.

```
April 1, 2020 by Olivier

This blog post shows a few different types of content that are supported and styled with Material styles. Basic typography, images, and code are all supported. You can extend these by modifying Markdown.js.

Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam.
```

Why its contents didnt displayed in my method.
Are there any wrong point of that ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Heisenberg i am also facing same kind of issue. how you have solved it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue just as a workaround.
The issue caused that 'import' gets the file path of the md file. Hence I get the file content using axios.

1. I modified Blog.js as follows.

   import axios from 'axios'; //add

   // other codes

   //const posts = [post1, post2, post3]; commented out

   // other codes

   export default function Blog() {
   const [poststate1, setPoststate1] = React.useState(); //add
   const [poststate2, setPoststate2] = React.useState(); //add
   const [poststate3, setPoststate3] = React.useState(); //add

   React.useEffect(() => { //add
   axios.get(post1).then(res => setPoststate1(res.data)); //add
   axios.get(post2).then(res => setPoststate2(res.data)); //add
   axios.get(post3).then(res => setPoststate3(res.data)); //add
   }, []); //add

   return (







   {featuredPosts.map((post) => (

   ))}

   <Grid container spacing={5} sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
   {/* modified the below */}
   {(poststate1 && poststate2 && poststate3) && }






   );
   }
2. (Option) Make axios able to access md file. In my enviroment, AWS Amplify blocked so I changed "rewrite and redirect" configuration such as "</^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json|**md**)$)([^.]+$)/>".

I'm glad that my answer helps you.